# What is the probability that if two cards are drawn from a standard deck without replacement that the first is red and the second is a heart?

Tags: probability

Two cards are drawn at random (without replacement) from a regular deck of 52 cards. What is the probability that the first card is a red and the second card is heart?
Let $A$ be the event that a red card is drawn and $B$ be the event the second card drawn is a heart.

We have;

$n(S) = C(52,2)$

$P(A) = \frac{26}{52}$

How is $P(B)$ calculated? Is a  solution even possible?

Comment: Do you know about conditional probability?

Comment: Yes I do. I understand that probability of two events occuring given that they are independent is the product of the probabilities of each and the probability of A and B occurring given that B depends on  A is P(A) * P(B|A) and vice versa.

Comment: TRy to draw a probability tree

Answer (score 1):

In a deck of cards, there are four suits: clubs, diamonds, hearts, and spades. Diamonds and hearts are red; clubs and spades are black.  There are $13$ cards of each suit.

We want to find the probability that the first card is red and the second card is a heart when two cards are drawn without replacement from a standard deck.

There are two possibilities:

1. The first card is a diamond and the second card is a heart.
2. Both cards are hearts.

Let $H$ denote the event that a heart is drawn; let $D$ denote the event that a diamond is drawn.

*The first card is a diamond and the second card is a heart*:  The probability of drawing a diamond on the first draw is $\Pr(D) = 13/52$.  Of the $51$ cards that remain, $13$ are hearts.  Hence, the probability of drawing a heart given that a diamond was selected on the first draw is $\Pr(H \mid D) = 13/51$.  Hence, the probability that the first card is a diamond and the second card is a heart is 
$$\Pr(H \mid D)\Pr(D) = \left(\frac{13}{51}\right)\left(\frac{13}{52}\right)$$

*Both cards are hearts*:  The probability of drawing a heart on the first draw is $\Pr(H) = 13/52$.  Of the $51$ cards that remain, $12$ are hearts.  Hence, the probability of drawing a heart given that a heart was drawn on the first draw is $\Pr(H \mid H) = 12/51$.  Thus, the probability that both cards are hearts is 
$$\Pr(H \mid H)\Pr(H) = \left(\frac{12}{51}\right)\left(\frac{13}{52}\right)$$

Since these cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the desired probability can be found by adding the probabilities for the two cases.

Comment: So just to clarify, referring back to my question, the probability of event A and event B occurring is equal to this sum? Im still trying to understand this.

Comment: Yes, the probability that a red card is drawn on the first draw and a heart is drawn on the second draw is $$\left(\frac{13}{51}\right)\left(\frac{13}{52}\right) + \left(\frac{12}{51}\right)\left(\frac{13}{52}\right)$$

Comment: If the question asked, what is the probability of getting a heart on the second draw given that we drew a red on the first draw, would we still have the same answer?

Comment: The conditional probability that we select a heart on the second draw given that we have selected a red card on the first draw is the probability of selecting a red card on the first draw and a heart on the second draw divided by the probability of selecting a red card on the first draw.   Since the probability of selecting a red card on the first draw is $1/2$, the conditional probability of drawing a heart on the second draw given that a red card has been selected on the first draw is twice the probability of selecting a red card on the first draw and a heart on the second draw.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Try to break it down by cases:

1) Case $1$: The first card is a heart and the second card is a heart

2) Case $2$: The first card is not a heart and the second card is a heart

Edit:
$$P(B)=P(B|H)P(H)+P(B|H^c)P(H^c)$$

Comment: I tried that but then got confused about how to proceed form there.

Comment: I added a formula, try to use the formula.

Comment: Im not sure what the superscript c's are suppose to mean. Could you please explain.

Comment: $H$ means the event that you get heart in the first draw, $H^c$ means you do not get heart in the first draw. I use superscript $c$ to denote complement of a set.

Comment: I did some looking around and I believe that the formula you are using is Bayes's Formula? I hadn't been introduced to this yet. Maybe more reading is required to get a better grasp of the question. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It seems like the other person to answer this has used the same formula as well.

Comment: What i proposed is known as [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability). This question just require a probability tree to solve. Yes, the other answer uses the same formula.

Comment: Another concept I'm not familiar with. I probably need to do more reading now.

Comment: Im still not sure I understand this. If you dont mind, what would the be the probability of both events A and B occurring?

Comment: a heart is a red card, hence if $B$ happens, $A$ must happen. Hence $P(A \cap B)=P(B)$.

Comment: What Im really having difficulty understanding here is how it is possible to calculate the probability of an event that is dependent on event that may or may not have already occurred. I feel like understanding this will lead to me understanding this question.

Comment: I see, when we write $P(B|H)$, we assume that $H$ already happens. Are you able to compute $P(B|H)$, the probability that the second card is a heart, if the first card is a heart. I am telling you, yes, we know that the first card is a heart. Similarly, when we compute $P(B|H^c)$, we assume that we know that $H$ did not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The following answer proposes a solution to the probability of the second card being drawn being hearts, interpreting that the question is not linked with the statement that the first card is red. If you take the question to actually need the first card to be red, please refer to N. F. Taussig's answer.

Let's define the events

$F = \{ \text{first card is hearts}\}$,
$S = \{  \text{second card is hearts}\}$

We want to calculate the probability that the second card is hearts, that is, we are looking for $P(S)$.

Now, we can break this experiment up into two distinct scenarios: either the first card you picked was hearts, or it wasn't ($F$ and $F^C$, respectively).

So, by conditional probability we have that
$$P(S) = P(S |F)P(F)+P(S |F^C)P(F^C)$$
hence
$$P(S) = \left(\dfrac{12}{51}\right)\left( \dfrac{13}{52} \right)+\left(\dfrac{13}{51}\right)\left( \dfrac{39}{52} \right)= \frac{1}{4}$$
since we have $13$ cards of each suit. Notice that this is the same as the probability of just picking a random card and getting hearts (why?).

Comment: You have introduced me to a new formula. Bayes's Formula I believe? I'm gonna do a little more reading and then come back to this. Thanks for the nudge in that direction.

Comment: It's the law of total probability. However, Bayes' Formula follows from this. So yes, definitely read up on both of these concepts, they are very important!

Comment: Be careful.  We need the probability that the second card is a heart given that the first card is red.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I did not interpret the question to be this. However, you may be right, we would need some clarification from the OP.